# POSIX shared memory: find out if anyone is attached to a segment

Tags: posix, shared-memory

In System V shared memory (`shmget()`), it is possible to find out how many attached users there are for a segment by using `shmctl(... IPC_STAT ...)` and reading the field `shm_nattch` of the resulting data structure.

With POSIX shared memory (`shm_open()`), is there any way to do something similar, or at least find out whether anyone is attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one way, somewhat cumbersome and probably not quite portable. You can scan `/proc` filesystem looking for processes that have this SHM object opened. Use `readlink` on `"/proc/<self-PID>/fd/<shm-FD>"` to get the object path, and then scan "`/proc/[0-9]+/fd/*` symlinks, comparing file names they point to or, better yet, device and inode numbers as returned by `stat`. Or you can simply delegate this task to `fuser` utility and parse its output.

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but as you say, not quite easy and portable. I think I prefer to maintain a separate system semaphore for the segment.